# Adding a column to an SQL table and exploding the rows with a set of fixed values for that column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to add a column to an SQL table with unknown columns and explode the entries in that table by a set of fixed values for that column. E.g. Turn

| unknown col 1 | ... | unknown col x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | foo |
| 2 | ... | bar |

into

| unknown col 1 | ... | unknown col x | new col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | foo | 1 |
| 2 | ... | bar | 1 |
| 1 | ... | foo | 2 |
| 2 | ... | bar | 2 |

The *number* of unknown columns is also unknown. I know the query to turn the original table into

| unknown col 1 | ... | unknown col x | new col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | foo | 1 |
| 2 | ... | bar | 1 |

I don't know the `INSERT` query that would turn it in to the desired table further above. The table is on **Google BigQuery**.

p.s: I can think of workarounds, e.g. multiply the number of rows in the original table by `n`, where `n` is the number of values the new column can take, then add the column and set the value based on the row number (which is not trivial to set) for each row. I am looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: If you don't know what the columns are (i.e. "unknown columns"), then I'm rather unclear on how you could add them at all.

Comment: Me too. It's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Do you at least know the primary key columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add a column to an SQL table with unknown columns and explode the entries in that table by a set of fixed values for that column.

Below should do the "trick" - example

```
with new_col_values as (
  select [1, 2, 3, 4] values
)
select t.*, val
from `project.dataset.your_table` t, 
new_col_values, unnest(values) val
```

Comment: Would this work before or after adding the new column? I'd say neither. (not being a douche, just double-checking).

Comment: not sure what you mean by your comment - above does exactly what you asked! just try it, play with it to get it :o)

Comment: just to clarify - above select statement can be used to create new table that match your "spec", so you can use along with CREATE TABLE ... or CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ...

Comment: Could you explain what is happening? - specifically, the part after the `from` clause.

Comment: You cross join your table with CTE that holds list of fixed values, than you unrest this list to set of those values and again cross join with original table - this gives you expected result.

Comment: Does CTE have one row?

Comment: How do you access a column in a `from` clause? I'm wondering what's the general rule here. Does this kind of thing have a name?

Comment: in your case  - yes - CTE has just one row with array of fixed values for new column

Comment: comma in list of from clause is equivalent of cross join - so `from \`project.dataset.your_table\` t, new_col_values` is equivalent of `from \`project.dataset.your_table\` t cross join new_col_values`